# Using gdb with GMP variables

Tags: c, gdb, gmp

I am debugging some C code with gdb. My program has a variable of type `mpz_t * retval`. If I run the command

```
print *retval
```

I get the output

```
$23 = {{
    _mp_alloc = 6, 
    _mp_size = 5, 
    _mp_d = 0x1001008d0
}}
```

Is there anything else I can do to get more information about the value stored in `retval`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try these:

```
(gdb) set print object on
(gdb) set print pretty on
(gdb) ptype *retval
(gdb) print *retval
```

What else do you you want to know?

Comment: I'd like to know what the value of `_mp_d` is. But if I try `print (*retval)._mp_d` then I get `Attempt to extract a component of a value that is not a structure`

Comment: What does `ptype retval->_mp_d` says? Tried `set print union on`?

Comment: Ah, I see. I needed `print *retval[0][0]._mp_d`, I found this using the ptype as you suggested. Thanks.

Comment: Oh, I see, that's an array. Didn't notice that on the first read.